# Python SQLite3 / Selecting rows from table

Tags: python, list, select, sqlite, tuples

```
board  balls  win1   win2   result
-----  -----  ----   ----   ------
    1      1     0      0        1
    4      1     0      0        1
 1024      1     0      0        1
```

When we are selecting only one row but multiple columns from a table, for example, by using:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("spline.db")
crsr = connection.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT board FROM positions WHERE balls = 1")
result = crsr.fetchall()
print result
connection.close()
```

The result is a list of tuples:

```
[(1,), (4,), (1024,)]
```

Is there any way to get a list of integers directly? One way to do it is with:

```
print [result[i][0] for i in range(len(result))]
```

instead of with:

```
print result
```

But whenever that there are as much as 10<sup>7</sup> rows in the result set, we cannot imagine of iterating the variable `i` like that, and then make a list of integers out of it. So, I would like to know that if there are any other alternative solutions available for it whichever are efficient enough quite directly.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Why is `fetchall()` necessary?

Comment: I am solving a strategy game called Spline by using Python. There are as much as 107529339 different possible board positions available and for each board position, I am storing the data related to it in a SQLite3 database to quickly retrieve with whether the board position is a win for the first player or second player. Board position is the primary key and so any searches with respect to it are faster. `crsr.fetchall()` is required to retrieve the list of tuples from the result set of `crsr`. Or that is it directly possible to access the data items from the result set of `crsr` itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `row_factory` attribute like this:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("spline.db")
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
crsr = connection.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT board FROM positions WHERE balls = 1")
result = crsr.fetchall()
print result
connection.close()
```

This should give you a list, instead of tuples.

You can read more about `row_factory` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to call `fetchall()`; you can iterate directly over the cursor:

```
crsr.execute("SELECT ...")
for row in crsr:
    print row[0]
```

This will compute the result rows on demand, so the entire list never needs to be kept in memory.

And you can simplify this further: `execute()` returns the cursor object itself, and you can use tuple assignment to extract the value(s) from the row:

```
for (board,) in crsr.execute("SELECT board FROM ..."):
    print board
```

Comment: Does `for (board,) in crsr.execute("SELECT board FROM ..."):` not make the SQLite query to be computed it again and again, computing it every time for each iteration? Is it not so?

Comment: No, `for` runs on the *result* of the `execute()` call. Try `for c in raw_input(): print c`

Comment: Thank you for your response. However that this statement (You do not need to call `fetchall()`; you can iterate directly over the cursor:) does not apply whenever that you are making use of multiple crsr.execute() statement calls inside of the same 'for' loop, unless you are using multiple cursor statements by making use of calls such as those statements like `crsr1 = connection.cursor()` and `crsr2 = connection.cursor()` or creating and storing intermediate results in between into any given temporary database table. Is it not so?

Comment: Yes, but this question is not about multiple `execute()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

There's almost never a good reason to iterate over `range(len(something))`. Always iterate over the thing itself.

```
[row[0] for row in result]
```