# Python/sqlite3 function compare : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, database, function, sqlite, web-applications

I'm new here can somebody help me please. I'm working on a components comparator webapp, the first page works normally but when I click on 'compare' ( that would launch the function and show the page) i just see the 'body' and not what the function would do. The server does not show an error message. When I try to launch manually the function in VsCode i got this error :

```
aprixProc1 = connexion.execute('SELECT prixProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?);',(processeur1,)).fetchone()[0] 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import cgi

formulaire = cgi.FieldStorage()
processeur1 = formulaire.getvalue('proc1')
processeur2 = formulaire.getvalue('proc2')

connexion = sqlite3.connect("composants.db")
connexion.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")

#Recupere le prix de proc1 et proc2  
aprixProc1 = connexion.execute('SELECT prixProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?);'(processeur1,)).fetchone()[0]
aprixProc2 = connexion.execute("SELECT prixProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?);" (processeur2,)).fetchone()[0]


#Recupere le nb de coeurs de proc1 et proc2  
anbCoeurs1 = connexion.execute("SELECT coeursProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)", (processeur1,)).fetchone()[0]  
anbCoeurs2 = connexion.execute("SELECT coeursProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)",(processeur2,)).fetchone()[0]

#Recupere le nb de threads de proc1 et proc2  
athreadsProc1 = connexion.execute("SELECT threadsProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)",(processeur1,)).fetchone()[0]  
athreadsProc2 = connexion.execute("SELECT threadsProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)",(processeur2,)).fetchone()[0]  

#Recupere la taille de gravure de proc1 et proc2  
agravProc1 = connexion.execute("SELECT gravProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)",(processeur1,)).fetchone()[0]  
agravProc2 = connexion.execute("SELECT gravProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)",(processeur2,)).fetchone()[0]




pagedebut = '''
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title> Components Stock Tracker </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/fichier_css_html.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="entete">
        <p class='phead'>Components Stock Tracker</p>
        <img src ="images/logo_cst.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="main">

'''

pagefin='''
</div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p class="texteFooter">
        Pied de Page <br> Crédits: Baptiste Lecerf </br>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html> 
'''

def compareProc(prixProc1, prixProc2, nbCoeurs1, nbCoeurs2, threadsProc1, threadsProc2, gravProc1, gravProc2):    
reponse = ''  
if prixProc1 < prixProc2:  
    reponse += str(prixProc1)  
else:  
    reponse+= str(prixProc2)  
if nbCoeurs1 < nbCoeurs2:  
    reponse+= str(nbCoeurs2)  
else:  
    reponse+= str(nbCoeurs1)  
if threadsProc1 < threadsProc2:  
    reponse+= str(threadsProc2)  
else:  
    reponse+= str(threadsProc1)  
if gravProc1 < gravProc2:  
    reponse+= str(gravProc1)  
else:  
    reponse+= str(gravProc2)  

print(pagedebut+reponse+pagefin)

print(compareProc(aprixProc1, aprixProc2, anbCoeurs1, anbCoeurs2, athreadsProc1, athreadsProc2, agravProc1, agravProc2))  
connexion.close()
```

Comment: That is not how you fetch results from DB, Have you read at least ONE tuto on how to do it ? https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python SQLite3 / Selecting rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074564/python-sqlite3-selecting-rows-from-table)

Comment: Also don't do 4 request for getting ONE attribut of the same row, retrieve in one request `SELECT prixProc,coeursProc, threadsProc ,gravProc    FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=(?)`

Comment: @azro yes but how i can compare each attribut after ?

Comment: No matter how many attributes, or how many rows you retrieve, all the data is in the result, just instead of having a list of 1 element, you have a list of multiple elements

Comment: I've just answered so you see

Comment: okay i did not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and some other things but I always get ' [(0,)] '

(with parenthesis around ? or without it's the same)

```
import sqlite3
import cgi

formulaire = cgi.FieldStorage()
#processeur1 = formulaire.getvalue('proc1')
processeur1 = "R5-3600"
#processeur2 = formulaire.getvalue('proc2')
processeur2 = "I9-10900K"

conn = sqlite3.connect("composants.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")


sql = "select exists(SELECT prixProc, coeursProc, threadsProc, gravProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc= (?) OR nomProc= (?))"
args = (processeur1, processeur2)
cursor = conn.execute(sql, args)
results = cursor.fetchall()


pagedebut ='''

'''    

pagefin ='''    

'''

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all values with one query, when the amount of value if not important, the less you fetch the DB the better it is.

- When you fetched one attribut, for one row, you use used `fetchone()[0]` for : first row first field
- Now you fetch multiple attribut, for multiples rows data came like this

  ```
  [[450, 4, 8, 16]
   [550, 8, 1, 17]]
  ```

```
connexion = sqlite3.connect("composants.db")
cursor = connexion.cursor()
cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")

cursor.execute(
    'SELECT prixProc, coeursProc, threadsProc, gravProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc=? OR nomProc=?;',
    (processeur1, processeur2))
results = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.close()
connexion.close()

pagedebut = '''    '''
pagefin = '''    '''

def maxItem(values, index):
    return max(values, key=lambda x: x[index])[index]

def minItem(values, index):
    return min(values, key=lambda x: x[index])[index]

def compareProc(values):
    # min prixProc
    reponse = str(minItem(values, 0)) + " / "
    # max coeursProc
    reponse += str(maxItem(values, 1)) + " / "
    # max threadsProc
    reponse += str(maxItem(values, 2)) + " / "
    # min gravProc
    reponse += str(minItem(values, 3))

    return pagedebut + reponse + pagefin

print(compareProc(results))
```

Don't `print(method())` if the `method` doesn't return anything,  it'll print `None` which the default return value, either do

```py
method()

# OR the method must 'return' something
print(method())
```

---

The following SQL query can be used to

```
'SELECT prixProc, coeursProc, threadsProc, gravProc FROM Processeur WHERE nomProc in (?, ?);'
```

Comment: i try your code,add this before: "import sqlite3
import cgi

formulaire = cgi.FieldStorage()
processeur1 = formulaire.getvalue('proc1')
processeur2 = formulaire.getvalue('proc2')  " and it doesn't work anyway. PS: I'm a beginner

Comment: here is the error: testCompareProc.py", line 70, in <module>
    print(compareProc(results))                                                                                                  testCompareProc.py", line 60, in compareProc
    reponse = str(minItem(values, 0)) + " / "                                                                                    testCompareProc.py", line 56, in minItem
    return min(values, key=lambda x: x[index])[index]
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: maybe i should explain you more about my project, im  working on a webapp and the main page is divided in 4 (for each components) and i used a php dropdown menu to show by exemple processors and the user select 2 then click on compare and launch this function. When you click it should show the same header and same footer, in the middle what the fonction should return but i just got header, footer and nothing in the middle even with your function

Comment: i tried to print(results) with processeur1 = "R5-3600" and processeur2 = "I9-10900K" which are items in my db but i get an empty list   []

Comment: @VorTekS see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343175/python-3-sqlite-parameterized-sql-query#answers you may remove the parenthesis, I did not see it as I just copied your code, see my edit on the SQL query

Comment: need help please

Comment: @VorTekS you're still stuck on reading from your DB ?? execute `SELECT prixProc, coeursProc, threadsProc, gravProc FROM Processeur` and share to see

Comment: I saw the error it creates an empty DB in an other folder and opens it. So i change my DB to this folder and now it works

Comment: @VorTekS Nice !! You can now think about voting up and accepting the answer (green tick on left of it) ;)